# How do I easily view the contents of each entry of a (x,y,z) array in the workspace?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to be able to display M(1,:,:), M(2,:,:), etc... in the Matlab workspace. But this only shows M(:,:,1)...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try shifting the dimensions of your matrix with:

```
permute(val, [3 1 2])
```

This essentially rotates the matrix so that the 3rd dimension would be the 1st, the 1st dimension would be the 2nd, and the 2nd dimension would be the 3rd.